# How to prevent pdf cache all browsers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, caching, http-headers, outputcache

Even when the physical path is filled out on the navigation bar of all browsers it's showing a cached file.

The PROBLEM(with big letters because it's a big problem for us now) is that I already has cleared the client browser cache through a remote connection and I also already has applied a recycle on server application pool, but I'm still facing the same old problem :/ Someone facing something similar?

The following list include the actions applied until now that has not solved the problem:

01 - Response header:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.ClearHeaders();
    filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("no-store, must-revalidate");
    filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0");
    filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Last-Modified", "Wed, 08 Jan 2014 15:39:15 GMT");
    filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Tue, 07 Jan 2014 15:39:15 GMT");

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

02 - Data annotation:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, VaryByParam = "none")]
public ActionResult Avaliacao(int id)
{...

}
```

03 - Timestamp:

```
var _contents = memStream.GetBuffer();
memStream.Close();
return File(_contents, "application/pdf",
"RelatorioMensal-" + participante.Numero.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("00000") + "-" +
lote.Id.ToString("0000") + "-" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".pdf");
```

04 - Application pool recycling

05 - Cache rule filter for .pdf files on IIS set to ***Prevent all caching***

06 - Output cache setting: ***Enable cache*** and ***Enable kernel cache*** unchecked for testing purposes

07 - Clear cache through the code:

```
OutputCacheAttribute.ChildActionCache = new MemoryCache("NewDefault");
```

Ps.: I'm a *MCSD - Web applications* but don't tell it to anyone until I get this "simple" problem solved. Thanks ;)

Comment: Eventually it's the decision of the browser which files it caches, and if it does, for how long.

Comment: @mkl I could agree with you if I hasn't seen a cached .pdf that was NOT requested by the client browser and was NOT in our server folder. It's so strange, it's driving me crazy...

Comment: *a cached .pdf that was NOT requested by the client browser and was NOT in our server folder* - that sounds like caching is not your major issue but something else injecting false PDFs into your client.

Comment: I don't know @mkl... But this was the reason I did the request by the physical path and the client browser showed me a cached .pdf of another client from same region/city here in Brazil.

Comment: Let me explain it better with this example: We have three clients with the ID 1, 2 and 3. The client ID 3 made a request, the .pdf file was successfully generated on our server with no problem. It's OK! Great! Then, the client ID 2 made a request and the .pdf file was successfully generated on our server with no problem but he is viewing the client ID 3 request. I make a remote access on this client machine for I make sure it has no cache any more. But when I fill out the navigator bar with the physical path for that .pdf file in our server folder it still showing me the client ID 3 .pdf file.

Comment: Finally, I deleted the generated .pdf file for the client ID 2 request and by calling it again through the physical path it showed a _500 Internal Server Error_ like it did with the client ID 1 that has no file generated.

Comment: *Then, the client ID 2 made a request and the .pdf file was successfully generated on our server with no problem but he is viewing the client ID 3 request.* - ok, this implies that this is *not* a client cache issue as the client 3 file should never ever have gotten near enough to client 2 to reach its cache at all. Your attempts to stop client browser caches from caching the file, therefore, don't attack the issue. Instead you should look at server-side or (possibly transparent) HTTP proxies used by the involved clients.

Comment: hmm yes, I think I should attack the HTTP proxies now. Maybe this is the way to go... I'm looking for some books or sites talking about it. I found only this one: [Proxy Caches](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#PROXY) Let give it a try ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, the proxy cache isn't the villain. I made contact with the network administrators of the clients and there no Proxies involved. The tested machines were outside of the shared proxy.

Comment: I'm thinking that it could be a _Cache Poisoning Attack_, an _URL poisoning_ or even a _DNS Injection_. I'll make some tests through a ssl connection and hopefully come back here with good news... tk!

Comment: @mkl I'd like to share with you that our problem was definitely solved. Now the whole site is under a SSL connection and all the .pdf files are correctly shown. As you said before _something else was injecting false PDFs into our clients_. Thank you!

Comment: Great you have solved it.